# Multiple Java version issue in Jenkins 2.319.1

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have instaled jenkins via helm charts and we have used kubernetes dynamic agents(jnlp-agents) and image we are using for agents is (jenkins/jnlp-agent-python).
Now the problem is i want to run a maven project which has java version 17 requirement but my jenkins has java version 11 installed.

SO i tried to build a pipeline on which it download the openjdk18 on dynamic node(agent) for running the pipeline.

```
pipeline {          
agent any
tools {
    jdk 'OpenJDK18'
    maven 'maven-3.8.5'
}
stages  {   
stage("prerequisits") {
    steps {
        sh '''
        env | grep -e PATH -e JAVA_HOME
        export JAVA_HOME=$PATH
        java -version
        '''
    }
}
stage("Checkout")   {   
    steps   {                                                                               
        git (
            url: 'git@github.ibm.com:watson/cloud-scheduling-api.git',  
            credentialsId: 'cloud-scheduling-api-sonarqube-ssh-key'
            )
            }                                       
                    }   
stage ("build") {
     steps {
         echo 'This is the build stage'
              sh 'mvn clean install -DskipTests'
              
                }
                       
               }
}
}
```

And its unable to find the JAVA_HOME

```
Started by user Jenkins Admin
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
Waiting for next available executor
Agent default-wxtw0 is provisioned from template default
---
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  labels:
    jenkins/jenkins-jenkins-agent: "true"
    jenkins/label-digest: "500b4f18aee87616849e4f4c2435020898e34aa0"
    jenkins/label: "jenkins-jenkins-agent"
  name: "default-wxtw0"
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - "********"
    - "default-wxtw0"
    env:
    - name: "JENKINS_SECRET"
      value: "********"
    - name: "JENKINS_TUNNEL"
      value: "jenkins-agent.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:50000"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_NAME"
      value: "default-wxtw0"
    - name: "JENKINS_NAME"
      value: "default-wxtw0"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR"
      value: "/home/jenkins"
    - name: "JENKINS_URL"
      value: "http://jenkins.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:8080/"
    image: "us.icr.io/watsonmedia-wlc/jnlp-agent-python:latest"
    imagePullPolicy: "Always"
    name: "jnlp"
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "2048Mi"
        cpu: "512m"
      requests:
        memory: "1024Mi"
        cpu: "512m"
    securityContext:
      privileged: false
      runAsUser: 1000
    tty: false
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
    workingDir: "/home/jenkins"
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: "bx-registry"
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: "linux"
  restartPolicy: "Never"
  serviceAccountName: "default"
  volumes:
  - emptyDir:
      medium: ""
    name: "workspace-volume"

Running on default-wxtw0 in /home/jenkins/workspace/cloud-api-test-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Tool Install)
[Pipeline] tool
Unpacking https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk18.0.2.1/db379da656dc47308e138f21b33976fa/1/GPL/openjdk-18.0.2.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz to /home/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/OpenJDK18 on default-wxtw0
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] tool
Unpacking https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.8.5/apache-maven-3.8.5-bin.zip to /home/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.8.5 on default-wxtw0
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (prerequisits)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ grep -e PATH -e JAVA_HOME
+ env
PATH=/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/OpenJDK18/openjdk18/bin:/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.8.5/bin:/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/OpenJDK18/openjdk18/bin:/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.8.5/bin:/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
JAVA_HOME=/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/OpenJDK18/openjdk18
+ export JAVA_HOME=/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/OpenJDK18/openjdk18/bin:/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.8.5/bin:/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/OpenJDK18/openjdk18/bin:/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.8.5/bin:/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
+ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8, mixed mode)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Checkout)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] git
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential cloud-scheduling-api-sonarqube-ssh-key
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@github.ibm.com:watson/cloud-scheduling-api.git
 > git init /home/jenkins/workspace/cloud-api-test-pipeline # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.ibm.com:watson/cloud-scheduling-api.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.30.2'
using GIT_SSH to set credentials cloud-scheduling-api-sonarqube-ssh-key-for-repo
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- git@github.ibm.com:watson/cloud-scheduling-api.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Avoid second fetch
Checking out Revision 2c0d2a25013835fe0579c3879b918e57a7d3aa70 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config remote.origin.url git@github.ibm.com:watson/cloud-scheduling-api.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 2c0d2a25013835fe0579c3879b918e57a7d3aa70 # timeout=10
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b master 2c0d2a25013835fe0579c3879b918e57a7d3aa70 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Merge pull request #43 from watsonmedia-wlc/wlc-1508"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 2c0d2a25013835fe0579c3879b918e57a7d3aa70 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] envVarsForTool
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
This is the build stage
[Pipeline] sh
+ env
+ grep -e PATH -e JAVA_HOME
PATH=/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/OpenJDK18/openjdk18/bin:/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.8.5/bin:/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/OpenJDK18/openjdk18/bin:/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.8.5/bin:/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
JAVA_HOME=/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/OpenJDK18/openjdk18
+ export JAVA_HOME=/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/OpenJDK18/openjdk18/bin:/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.8.5/bin:/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/OpenJDK18/openjdk18/bin:/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven-3.8.5/bin:/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
+ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.13+8 (build 11.0.13+8, mixed mode)
[Pipeline] sh
+ mvn clean install -DskipTests
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

To help Maven to find Java, you should change the environment accordingly:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/OpenJDK18/openjdk18
```

**NOT**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/OpenJDK18/openjdk18/bin
```

Comment: Hint: the problem is in 'prerequisits', when you assign 'export JAVA_HOME=$PATH'